# Would 'piqued' in 'piqued interest' be classified as a fossil word?

Tags: word-usage

Are there any other common collocations using 'piqued' that would prevent it from being classified as such?

Comment: Your curiosity can be as *piqued* as your interest, and in a slightly more negative sense you can *piqued* directly. Meanwhile *piqued fabric* is sometimes used for *piqué*.

Comment: It is certainly not a fossil word. It is possible that only well-educated or well-read native English speakers use it, and then, not often, but most native English speakers will understand it, especially when used in a phrase such as "it piqued my interest".

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fit+of+pique&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfit%20of%20pique%3B%2Cc0), the collocation ***fit of pique*** has been steadily *gaining* traction over the past two centuries. So it's hardly a "fossil" word.

Comment: Not to be confused with *peaked*. A fit of pique left her looking peaked.

Comment: Although he couldn't carry a tune, he piqued himself in his ability to hit the high note.  I don't know what a fossil word is, but I think the construction above at least long in the tooth.

Answer (score 2):

***[to pique](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pique_2)*** is a formal rather than a fossil  term:

> - pique somebody/something (formal) **to make somebody annoyed or upset***.
>
>   - The incident piqued his pride.

Its main usage is in the idiomatic expression :

> - ***pique somebody’s interest, curiosity, etc.***:
>
>   - *to make somebody very interested in something*

From: OLD

The term [pique](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pique) is a very old and its idiomatic usage is actually increasing as shown in ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piqued%20my%20interest%2Cpiqued%20my%20curiosity&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpiqued%20my%20interest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiqued%20my%20curiosity%3B%2Cc0):***

> - "meaning "to stimulate, excite" is from 1690s" .

From: Etymonline